# Is there any way to save information about open tabs if the page was closed?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that receives a URL and opens it in a new browser tab.

```
  window.open('someURL','myWindow').focus();
```

After that, the current page is closed.

```
  window.open('','_self').close();
```

The next time my page loads, the received url opens in a new tab.
How to make the received url open in an existing tab?

I cannot save the window object to localStorage, but maybe I can save the information about the tabs associated with it?

Comment: Do you have an example of any existing web application that does this? If I understand what you are trying to do, I don't think I have ever seen this anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot name an existing application with such behavior, this is specific to my project. And I also have doubts that this can be implemented.

Comment: Are the open tabs external links?

Comment: No, they don't. Thanks for answers. I came to the conclusion that this functionality is not possible because it is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage... The stored data is saved across browser sessions.

Set value:

```
 localStorage.setItem('key', 'VALUE');
```

Retrive value:

```
 const menu = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

If you want to remove keyValue pair:

```
 localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Comment: I know about local storage, but as I said, I cannot save the window object to it. Is it possible to save information about tabs in it so that later it can be reused for a new window?

Comment: The tab that gets open is it your page or external page?